# Why does -10 / 500 = 0 in SQL?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have to do a calculation that required dividing a negative number by a positive number.

I'm using SQLite and when I put in `SELECT -10 / 500` then output is 0.

Why is that the case?

Comment: Because your database does integer division.  You can do `10.0 / 500` to get a number with decimal points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because, SQL considers both -10 and 500 as Integers and so it gives the output as an integer here. You can change either of them or both as decimal and by doing so, you will get the desired result.